# No view found for id 0x7f070000 for fragment

Tags: java, android

I get this error when I try to load my `Fragment` in my `ActionBar`.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id
>   0x7f070000 for fragment HomeFragment{4100e030 #0 id=0x7f070000}

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    }    
}
```

The below is my mainActivity

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prime_mobile_home);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        Tab homeTab = actionBar.newTab();
        homeTab.setText("Home");
        homeTab.setIcon(R.drawable.home);

        Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

        homeTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(homeFragment));

        actionBar.addTab(homeTab);

    }
```

MainActivity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should input viewGroup resource ID which is ContentView in ParentActivity.

does you Parent Activity have LinearLayout or Relativelayout as ContentView.

if yes, you should choose it in inflate method's augument.

Comment: please paste mainActivity layout XML

Comment: you have to set contentView in layoutXML file.